# For Loop not working as expected in R

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, data-analysis, data-manipulation

I have a variable `precip` in a dataframe `parleys_data` in R, and I'm trying to generate a vector `precip_memory` using this variable. An element in the generated vector would be the sum of the element having the same index in the `precip` variable and the previous element (index-1) in the `precip` variable. But the new vector should reset to 0 after 5 elements are processed in the `precip` variable. Therefore, the new vector is the accumulated sum of the elements in the `precip` variable, reset to 0 (zero) after every 5 elements.

(Note: The first element in the new vector `precip_memory` is taken as zero by default)

For example:

```
precip = 1 2 3 4 1 7 3 5 1 5 6 7 8 1

precip_memory = 0 2 5 9 0 7 10 15 16 0 5 11 17 24 0 8 9
```

I have the following code for this (with the loop set to process only 50 elements initially):

```
precip_memory=rep(NA,50)
precip_memory[1]=0
c=0
for (i in 1:50){
  c=c+1
  precip_memory[i+1]=parleys_data$precip[i+1]+precip_memory[i]
  if(c==5){
    precip_memory[i]=0
    c=0
  }
```

I get a wrong result when I run the code, and I'm not sure what's happening.

My data looks like this:

```
>head(parleys_data$precip,n=20)
[1] 0.1 0.0 0.3 0.1 0.9 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

So my result should be:

```
0 0 0.3 0.4 0 0.1 0.3 ........
```

But I get:

```
0.0 0.0 0.3 0.4 0.0 1.4 1.6 1.7 1.8 0.0 1.8 1.8 1.8 1.8 0.0 1.8 1.8 1.8 1.8 0.0
```

Thanks!

Comment: put the `if` statement prior to the assignment `precip_memory[i+1]=...`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want the `cumsum` of every item within groups of 5 except for the first position within these groups:

```
> precip=scan()
1:  0.1 0.0 0.3 0.1 0.9 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
21: 
Read 20 items

> ave(precip, rep(1:4, each=5), FUN= function(x) c(0, cumsum(x[-1]) ) )
 [1] 0.0 0.0 0.3 0.4 1.3 0.0 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.4 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Using the `rep` function to build the INDEX or grouping variables for the `tapply` or `ave` functions is an easy way to construct grouped operations. It gets you in the vectorized/functional mindset (and away from the for-loop habits.) There is also a `gl` function that can build grouping factors.